# Uncaught (in promise) The executing command state is locked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to integrate a javascript library [(An Image Editor)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tui-image-editor) inside an angular JS app. How ever I was able to do it successfully, Now I need to use some of built in methods of the library, but I have encountered an error which is in the title of this post.

> Uncaught (in promise) The executing command state is locked.

I can not use a simple method to receive the required details. Here is the code I've been working on. If someone could help me to sort this out that would be really grate.

```js
angular.module('testapp', [])
  .factory('ImageEditor', ['$window', function($window) {
    return $window.ImageEditor;
  }])
  .controller('testCtrl', ['$window', function($scope) {
    var imageEditor = new tui.ImageEditor('#tui-image-editor-container', {
      includeUI: {
        loadImage: {
          path: './img/test.png',
          name: 'SampleImage'
        },
        theme: whiteTheme,
        menuBarPosition: 'bottom'
      },
      cssMaxWidth: 700,
      cssMaxHeight: 500,
      selectionStyle: {
        cornerSize: 20,
        rotatingPointOffset: 70
      }
    });

    imageEditor.addText('Init Text');

    window.onresize = function() {
      imageEditor.ui.resizeEditor();
    }
  }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testapp">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ImageEditor</title>
  <link type="text/css" href="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui-color-picker/v2.2.0/tui-color-picker.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui-image-editor/latest/tui-image-editor.css">
  <style>
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans);
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
  

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/tui-image-editor/examples/js/theme/white-theme.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/tui-image-editor/examples/js/theme/black-theme.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <div id="tui-image-editor-container"></div>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.7/fabric.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui.code-snippet/v1.3.0/tui-code-snippet.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nhnent/tui.color-picker/v2.2.0/dist/tui-color-picker.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tui-color-picker@2.2.0/dist/tui-color-picker.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui-image-editor/latest/tui-image-editor.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I suspect it's because you're calling `imageEditor.addText()` before the image is actually loaded (hence the error about locked state). To confirm this, try putting the call inside a timeout (i.e. `setTimeout(() => imageEditor.addText('Init Text'), 1000)`. The Toast UI documentation doesn't seem to point out how to be notified when an image finishes loading.

Comment: Thank you @miqid. It solves my problem with addText(). Hope I can use this direction to try out other inbuilt methods also.

Answer (score 0):

For production code you don't need a timeout, just a promise chain. That way the next steps will fire synchronously (ie as soon as the load is completed). Something like this:

```
angular.module('testapp', [])
    .factory('ImageEditor', ['$window', function($window) {
    return $window.ImageEditor;
  }])
.controller('testCtrl', ['$window', function($scope) {
  var imageEditor = new tui.ImageEditor('#tui-image-editor-container', {
    includeUI: {
      theme: whiteTheme,
      menuBarPosition: 'bottom'
    },
    cssMaxWidth: 700,
    cssMaxHeight: 500,
    selectionStyle: {
      cornerSize: 20,
      rotatingPointOffset: 70
    }
  });

  imageEditor.loadImageFromFile('./img/test.png', 'SampleImage').then(() => {
    imageEditor.addText('Init Text');
    // more things here if you like
  });

  window.onresize = function() {
    imageEditor.ui.resizeEditor();
  }
}]);
```

Comment: I use this library inside a angularJS controller, and I call this controller from a angularJS `factory`. the editor wasn't initiate at all without a timeout. gives me this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null`. Do you have any suggestions about this? But with the time out, it works just fine. I had to put the entire code snippet above inside a `setTimeout` to work this around.

Comment: I've expanded my example snippet - have you wrapped it like that?

Comment: As @miqh says, it isn't clear that the image load has completed. ToastUI Image Editor appears to have promises for all functions but the constructor has no such guarantee with includeUI load option. I had hoped you could defer the file details and do that subsequently when a promise is available, but seemingly not (as evidenced by the absent classList property). So for the moment the setTimeout is the way to go, and take the 1sec delay. You could also approach ToastUI on GitHub and raise it as an issue, perhaps.  [https://github.com/nhnent/tui.image-editor/issues]

Comment: Ya, I get your point. I already open few issues regarding the image editor behaviors. And not specifically, but I raised an issue for asking a angular JS version for the editor, but still no response for that from them. So for the time I have to stick to this method. Thank toy for your time for looking for the matter @Miles